# How to take id from url and pass it to function?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem. I have textbox where i need to enter a pin and button for submit, and when user click on button i get popupt that contains data for that pin. When user click on that button it display url something like this :

```
http://localhost:60664/#?ticketid=87879578
```

Now i need to handle function when i open in another window that link to be able to see that popup. How can i do that?

This is my function that works on click:

```
$scope.ShowDetails = function (pin) {
    if ($scope.showdetail == false && pin != null) {
        $scope.pin = pin;


        $http.get(Url + 'Get/' + $scope.pin)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
            {
               $("#background").addClass("darker");
                $scope.showdetail = true;
                $scope.NotFound = false;
                $location.search('pinid', pinTicket);


            })
            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                $scope.NotFound = true;
                $scope.showdetail = false;



        })
       .then(Details, ErrorResponse);

    }

}
```

Comment: so basically do you need to take this ticketid=87879578 from that url? It's not clear

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get url parameter jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery)

Comment: i dont need jquery...i want to call specific function on load if there is ticketid ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$location.search().ticketid
```

should do the trick

so if you want to check if the url has an id, and if it has, run a function

```
if($location.search().ticketid) {
  myFunction($location.search().ticketid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this should provide you the params
var urlParams= $location.search(); 

//in your case, urlParams would be {ticketid: '87879578'}
//access ticketid as
var ticketId = urlParams['ticketid'] // or as $location.search().ticketid.

if(ticketId){
    // do something here
}
//if u want it to set to a different value sometime later, use following,
$location.search('ticketid', '12548585');
```